# Getting error cannot read property 'stripe' of undefined (Meteor)

Tags: node.js, meteor

I an new to Meteor framework and trying to setup Meteor project in my local system and its showing below error. I tried googling but didnt find the solution.

```
/Users/progeshsubba/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.4_1.zu6xaw.bnn3++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
                    throw(ex);
                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'stripe' of undefined
at meteorInstall.server.methods.plans.methods.js (server/methods/plans/methods.js:3:32)
at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:197:9)
at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:120:16)
at /Users/progeshsubba/Desktop/surveyand/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/app.js:2672:1
at /Users/progeshsubba/Desktop/surveyand/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:303:34
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/progeshsubba/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.4_1.zu6xaw.bnn3++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
at /Users/progeshsubba/Desktop/surveyand/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:128:5
at /Users/progeshsubba/Desktop/surveyand/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:352:5
at Function.run (/Users/progeshsubba/Desktop/surveyand/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:510:12)
at /Users/progeshsubba/Desktop/surveyand/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:351:11
```

Comment: Show your code. It clearly says that some var is undefined ao you cannot call its method stripe either. Also, it clearly says the file (server/methods/plans/methods.js) and the line (3) where the error is thrown. Go and fix